# How to work with large images on Blazor/ Web

Tags: html, web, blazor, blazor-webassembly

my question is how to manage really large images on the web. Im using blazor, I need to send and recive Images of 100mb or more, And im using webshockets to send btwin the web and the server that send images. Im using base64 but its also slow.
this is how i send and i recive an image

```
    public class WebshocketConections
    {
        public Uri _Uri = new Uri("ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:YYYY");
        ClientWebSocket _cliente;
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
        public delegate void CheckNewMessage(string a);
        public event CheckNewMessage? onMessage;
        public WebshocketConections(ClientWebSocket client, Uri uri)
        {
            _cliente = client;
            _Uri = uri;
        }

        public async Task Connect()
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
            await _cliente.ConnectAsync(_Uri, cts.Token);
            await Echo(_cliente);
        }
        public async Task SendString(string message)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> byteToSend = await Task.Run(() => { return new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)); });
            await _cliente.SendAsync(byteToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cts.Token);
        }
        public async Task SendImage(byte[] Base64)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> byteToSend = await Task.Run(() => { return new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("img" + Convert.ToBase64String(Base64))); });
            await _cliente.SendAsync(byteToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, cts.Token);
        }

        public async Task<ClientWebSocket> GetClient()
        {
            return _cliente;
        }

        private async Task Echo(ClientWebSocket client)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1000000];
            var receiveResult = await client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                onMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count));
                await client.SendAsync(
                    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
                    receiveResult.MessageType,
                    receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
                    CancellationToken.None);

                receiveResult = await client.ReceiveAsync(
                    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), 
                    CancellationToken.None);


            }

            await client.CloseAsync(
                receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
                receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
                CancellationToken.None);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a 1GB buffer?

Comment: bc i want to upload bigg images